# Refresh data in footer custom console component as I switch between Primary Tabs

Tags: service-console, custom-service-console

I have a VF page which contains LWC component which display data retrieved by making callout to a 3rd party application. Data displayed are based on Case Record specific.

I want to use the VF page in **custom console component**  which in turn will be placed on footer of service console application.

**NOTE: Use case is in Salesforce Classic, should be lightning ready.**

**Objective**

As soon as user switch between Primary Tabs (Case), The custom console component created above should get the CaseId > Make a callout for data> Display the data.

In essence data displayed in console component should be refreshed as user switch between Primary Tabs.

See the Screenshot :

for example : if I am looking at case **00916533** I see **Support Marquees** console component data specific to **00916533** case and if switch to case **00916532** ,**Support Marquees** should get refreshed to show data relevant to **00916532**

**How to implement this ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for console apps you cannot create a generic code which will work for both classic and lightning, as there are two different APIs.

For lightning we have **Lightning Console API : [Lightning Console JavaScript API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_lightning.htm)**
For Classic we have **salesforce classic API : [Salesforce Console API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_classic.htm)**

For this specific use case, you can listen to [onFocusedPrimaryTab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_onfocusedprimarytab.htm) in classic but for the same thing to work in lightning you would need to register [TabFocusedEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_events_tabfocused.htm) and then use their own respective handlers to fire events which can be listened in the Utility app component.

Then do you processing there.

**NOTE**: Console api's are method are not yet exposed in LWC so the above solution only works in VF pages and Aura Components.